# Google Maps v3 API - Drawing Circles on Map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What I'm trying to do is draw a circle on google maps and retrieve the latitude/longitude/radius to store in a database, alternatively a geometry object would also be fine.

Using the standard code from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools i created the map and drawing toolbox. What i can't seem to do is get the lat/long/radius from the map using javascript, surely this must be possible.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Note - my code is identical to the google example, i figured it was better to link to it rather than copying ~60+ lines of html into a post.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawing

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'circlecomplete', function(circle) {
      var radius = circle.getRadius(),
      center = circle.getCenter();
});
```

Edit: getCenter()

Comment: great, that worked - i would assume the radius is measured in meters? Do you know how to get the latitude/longitude of the centre of the circle? Thanks in advance.